# php - get null from requesting data from server

Tags: php, mysql, webview

I request this php from my cloud server

```
http://54.249.251.55/php/1_index.php
```

But the result is null which is I try on my local it give me a json result.

```
localhost/php/1_index.php
```

HERE IS MY PHP

```
<?php

mysql_connect("54.249.251.55","MYID","MYPASS"); //connect database
mysql_select_db("aubook");//select name of the database
$cmd = "select * from book limit 0,20";
$sql=mysql_query($cmd);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();

?>
```

What happen to this my Data in MYSQL both server and local is the same

Do you have any sugestion??

On localhost I get this data

```
[{"bid":"B001","name":"Software design structure for Ebook application","booktype":"research","authorid":"5555555","url":"n\/a","description":""},{"bid":"B002","name":"High-level code generation for ebook viewer ontology","booktype":"research","authorid":"5555554","url":"n\/a","description":""},{"bid":"B003","name":"Toward study of photo capturing for a class of plantation investigation","booktype":"research","authorid":"1234567","url":"n\/a","description":""},{"bid":"B004","name":"Unique solution to extract spiral DNA from monkey typeA","booktype":"research","authorid":"7654321","url":"n\/a","description":""}]
```

Please help

Thank in advance

Comment: why not try `localhost` instead of `54.249.251.55` for [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/mysql_connect)? also check out [error messages](http://php.net/mysql_error).

Comment: maybe the external db-access for your ip is restricted, so you have to use localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: ahh I mean I want to use this server as a host for localhost is no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just temporarily while debugging, you'll need to expand the code a little to explain it:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("54.249.251.55","MYID","MYPASS"); //connect database
echo mysql_error();
mysql_select_db("aubook");//select name of the database
echo mysql_error();

$cmd = "select * from book limit 0,20";
$sql=mysql_query($cmd);
echo mysql_error();

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $output[]=$row;

if (count($output) == 0)
    echo "The database contained no records.";

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Can't connect to MySQL server on '54.249.251.55' (111)Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'aubook'No database selectedThe database contained no records.null [can you interpret this for me?? are there any solution?]

Comment: Yep - on the server, that user doesn't have access to the database - so all the following requests fail as well. You should check that the MYID user has been granted access.

Comment: actually I can login to phpmyadmin on cloud server with my user and pass so?? >..<